# Getting an error when trying to install Truffle on Windows Powershell

Tags: blockchain, nft

I'm trying to install Truffle by using this command:

```
 npm install -g truffle@5.0.2
```

and I get the following message:

> npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)

I downloaded Node.js v16.13.2 as well. Any clue what the error is all about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The message you have posted is a WARN (warning) and not an ERR (error), so there should be no problem with installing truffle in the system. I don't have windows rn, so I don't know what is your exact issue but if it is just WARN than there should be no problem installing NPM package.

Comment: It's weird because now I'm getting a whole list of error messages lol